# Working with Ajax Promises / Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I am trying to get an `Ajax promise` using the code below. Because my function makes another ajax call before initiating the actual one , for getting the `authKey`, The promise *(that should have been returned)* from the actual call is null, & I cannot use `.then()` on it because I think I am not getting anything in return from it. I am not sure why.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to go about this. I call getAjaxPromise() like mentioned below but get null in return:

```js
   getAjaxPromise(myUrl, true, myType, myContentType, mySuccessFunction, myFailureFunction, 
myData, true)
.then(function(data) //.then() gives undefined-null error
      {
        //Do something with the data returned form actual Ajax call.
      });
```

```js
self.getAjaxPromise = function(url, async, type, contentType, successCallback, 
errorCallback, data, isSecureCall) 
{
  if (isSecureCall) {
    var tokenPromise = getTokenPromiseFromServer(); //Another Ajax call to get latest token from service
    tokenPromise.then(function(tokenData) {  //This then runs fine
      return $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("authKey", tokenData.key);
        },
        url: url,
        async: async,
        type: type,
        contentType: contentType,
        success: successCallback, //Success callback runs fine, then() does not
        error: errorCallback, //Error callback runs fine, then() does not
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    });
  } else { //Just one ajax call 
    return $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("authKey", "anonymous");
      },
      url: url,
      async: async,
      type: type,
      contentType: contentType,
      success: successCallback,
      error: errorCallback,
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  });
}
};
```

Comment: There seem to be multiple syntax errors in the posted code ?

Comment: what is your query version ?

Comment: I modified the code to make it more simplified, Let me check, there may be some parentesis left behind, I will fix that. In actual, there are no syntax error- just to clarify,

Comment: @Ali.MD jquery-1.11.1.min

Comment: Its not your issue but  
I recommend to you to use v2 or if you must use v1 use v1.5 because its improved in ajax requests  
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Ali.MD I think I am not going to downgrade to 1.5 but I will try upgrading it to 2, if nothing breaks.

Comment: @zeppelin oops, i'm sorry, i think you write 1.1.1

Comment: haha I also thought you must've misread. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to return the getTokenPromiseFromServer
if isSecureCall is true your function return null

```js
self.getAjaxPromise = function(url, async, type, contentType, successCallback, 
errorCallback, data, isSecureCall) 
{
  if (isSecureCall) {
    return getTokenPromiseFromServer().then(function(tokenData) {
      return $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("authKey", tokenData.key);
        },
        url: url,
        async: async,
        type: type,
        contentType: contentType,
        success: successCallback, //Success callback runs fine, then() does not
        error: errorCallback, //Error callback runs fine, then() does not
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    });
  } else { //Just one ajax call 
    return $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("authKey", "anonymous");
      },
      url: url,
      async: async,
      type: type,
      contentType: contentType,
      success: successCallback,
      error: errorCallback,
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  });
}
};
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought the return inside tokenPromise's then() will be enough, But it makes sense now, then would only execute after response from server, not immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You had forgot to return the promise inside the if statement, you are return  it only on else, the fixed code below:

```js
self.getAjaxPromise = function(url, async, type, contentType, successCallback,
  errorCallback, data, isSecureCall) {
  if (isSecureCall) {
    var tokenPromise = getTokenPromiseFromServer(); //Another Ajax call to get latest token from service
    tokenPromise.then(function(tokenData) {
      return $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("authKey", tokenData.key);
        },
        url: url,
        async: async,
        type: type,
        contentType: contentType,
        success: successCallback, //Success callback runs fine, then() does not
        error: errorCallback, //Error callback runs fine, then() does not
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    });

    return tokenPromise;
  } else { //Just one ajax call 
    return $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("authKey", "anonymous");
      },
      url: url,
      async: async,
      type: type,
      contentType: contentType,
      success: successCallback,
      error: errorCallback,
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  });
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return tokenPromise
you must return it from first if

```
if (isSecureCall) {
    var tokenPromise = getTokenPromiseFromServer(); //Another Ajax call to get latest token from service

    // ...

    return tokenPromise;
  }
```