# Queue ajax requests if another one is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have an application that gets an authentication token in every service call's response and it is supposed to send the previous token as a parameter for the next call otherwise user will be unauthorized. And once the token is mismatched, all the other calls fail.

To make sure that the tokens are not mismatched, i have added loaders on my screen and i display them as soon as an ajax call is initiated and keep the loading overlay on screen until the response is not received otherwise the user could click on any other link which would result in another ajax call.

But still, i think the loader mechanism is prone to loopholes. Is there any way to check if any ajax call is in progress, then queue the new one and the queued one shall wait for the initiated ones response because it would need the token returned from its response as its new request parameter.

Comment: It sounds plausible to have a request for ajax either execute immediately, and store a Promise of that request in a singleton variable, or if it sees that singleton is occupied, perform its request afterward. You may want to be aware that any request timeouts in this system will leave you in a pretty uncertain state, since your token might have been invalidated by the server, or it might not. It's unfortunately hard to show you "how" with no code presented. You may want to at least try putting together a pseudocode example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098316/working-with-ajax-promises-deferred I had posted another query earlier, there I have code for my ajax call around which the handling/queuing of other ajax calls would revolve around when i implement it.

Comment: Regarding the timeout part. If one request is timedout then the next call will be made, if the token was regenerated on server side then user will get logged out because of wrong token otherwise the same old token would be used. I think tineout would be a rare case which is not going to be a major problem. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I just worked on a project where I did this. Let's say you've got your AJAX function, `foo.ajax( url, callback )`.

You need a way to package all the details that would go out in an AJAX request. So you make a function `foo.ajaxRequest(url)` and a list of requests, `foo.requestList = []` and use them like this:

```
foo.ajaxRequest = function( url ) {
    foo.requestList.push(this);
    var callback = function( data ) {
        if ( foo.requestList.length ) {
           foo.requestList.shift().run( data );
        }
    }
    this.run = function( dataFromPreviousAjax ) {
        foo.ajax( url + "?key=" + dataFromPreviousAjax, callback );
    }
    if ( !foo.requestList.length ) {
        foo.ajax( url, callback ); 
    }
}
```

and any time you want to make some requests, you write

```
new foo.ajaxRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/pingback.php");
new foo.ajaxRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/pingback.php");
```

and now suppose the first request returns a key of `12345`, the second request will now run and call the url `"http://stackoverflow.com/pingback.php?key=12345"`.

Obviously you'd want to do more stuff with the return value in the callback function inside `foo.ajaxRequest`, but this should get you started.

Comment: This seems right. I would try this and let you know if this works alright.

Comment: What if the `foo.ajax()` returns a promise, as with `jQuery.ajax()` or angular's `$http()`? As written above, the caller is denied access to the promise (or a derivative of it).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good point. What would you want to do with the promise, though? The main idea here is to jailhouse the ajax function so that you cannot have two running at the same time; if we return a promise would we still have that guarantee... ?

Comment: Without the capability for the caller to to do something with AJAX-derived data, or handle an AJAX-error, AJAX calls are pretty well useless. IMHO, a full solution should do all the usual stuff *and* perform the metering/key-propagation to meet the OP's requirements. I can't see why both would not be achievable.